# Disabling navigationg to MySite when clicking username

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user-profile-service

We have set up profile synchronization and mysite, but client didn't like the idea behind mysite and decided to shut it down.

But there is still a little problem - when user clicks user name of another user (eg. author of post in discussion) he is then taken to mysite web application to show that user profile - I'd like to disable this feature. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: it must be possible. What do they do in foundation? I think that link points to the root web's user list. Anyone know how to fake the user list template into using the foundation link instead of the user profile link?

Answer (score 1):

What if you stop and delete the User Profile Application and delete the My Site Host. That should rid your farm of any notion of people. Of course you'll have to remove the People Search tab from the search center.

Comment: We can't delete user profile application - we need to sync with AD because we ADFS.

Comment: What does the User Profile Service have to do with AD and ADFS? The user profile is not part of Authentication.